# What to put in the callback URL of Cognito user pool app client for account linking with FB Messenger?

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to set up account linking between a FB Messenger bot and AWS Cognito user pool using OAuth.

I have used Messenger account linking button template and pointed it to my Cognito domain login endpoint. Then set the callback URL in Cognito app client as https://facebook.com/messenger_platform/account_linking/ since that is what Messenger sends.

I keep getting a "redirect_mismatch" error from Cognito. I have observed that the redirect URI appended by Messenger while login has a query string parameter called "account_linking_token". Does that have something to do with it? Since the account_linking_token is dynamic and changes with every request.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the Redirect URI in Cognito isn't 1:1 with the URI that you are obtaining with the dynamic query string parameter. Currently, Cognito does not support Regex or pattern-based strings in the Callback/Redirect URI.

If you do not have a Callback URI that is rock-solid and isn't prone to change, you would not be able to achieve your functionality with Amazon Cognito.

Hence, you would get the `"redirect_mismatch"` error that you are seeing, and there is no Cognito quirk that can avert this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know any OAuth-compatible server that supports dynamic query string parameter for callback URL?

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging my answer. Unfortunately, most of my OAuth knowledge is currently limited to leveraging it on Cognito, so I am not aware of any providers. I did some quick Google searches on my end, and I was unable to get servers satisfying your use-case.